# Output of a r2c 3d fftw transform is not n/2+1

Tags: c++, fftw

I have a 3d array containing a sphere where inside the spherical boundary the data points are one and outside the spherical boundary the data points are 0. I want to take a fftw of this array and then ifftw it back. I should end up back with the sphere.

Here is my code:

```
int num = 100;
int cube = pow(num, 3);
int i, j, k;

fftw_complex *out;
double *in, *fin;

/* Allocate memory*/
out = (fftw_complex *) fftw_malloc(num * num* (num/2 +1) sizeof(fftw_complex));
in = (double *) fftw_malloc(cube * sizeof(double));
fin = (double *) fftw_malloc(cube * sizeof(double));


/* Initialize fft & ifft plans */
fftw_plan plan;
fftw_plan inv_plan1 ;
plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_3d(num,num,num, in, out,FFTW_MEASURE);
inv_plan1 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_3d(num, num, (num/2 +1), out, fin, FFTW_MEASURE);

int q = 0;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{
 for (j = 0; j < num; j++) 
  {
   for (k = 0; k < num; k++) 
    {
      in[q] = vals[i][j][k];
      q++;
    }
  }
}

fftw_execute(plan);
fftw_execute(inv_plan1);

for (k = 0; k < cube; k++) 
{
  fin[k] =fin[k]/(cube);
}
```

When I execute this and then plot a slice through the resulting data set I get an image that contains many streaks (looks nothing like a sphere). However, if I change the dimensions of out from num * num * (num/2 +1) to num * num * num and the dimensions of inv_plan1 from num, num, (num/2 +1) to num, num, num then I get back the sphere. I am confused because from reading the fftw3 documentation for a r2c transformation if the input dimensions are n0 x n1 x n2, then the complex output should be n0 x n1 x (n2/2 + 1). Why is this not the case for the sphere?

(Also I am very new to c++, this is the first script I have written ! )